# ASP.NET C# inserting multiple values in single field in MongoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I am trying to store names of team members of a project in the same field in `MongoDB` using ASP.NET.
The value is read correctly but I am having trouble creating a new entry.

Below is my controller. Simply writing the `document.insert()` doesn't work as it only stores a single value and not a list.

```cs
public ActionResult InsertProject(Projectdata model)
{
    _dbContext = new MongoContext();
    if (Request.Cookies["Userdata"] == null)
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
    }
    var document2 = _dbContext._database.GetCollection<Mongodata>("mainuser_data");
    var users = document2.FindAll().ToList(); 

    var document = _dbContext._database.GetCollection<ProjectItem>("project_data");
    string project = model.pname;

    var query = Query<ProjectItem>.EQ(model2 => model2.pname, project);
    var count = document.FindAs<ProjectItem>(query).Count();
    if (count == 0)
    {

        var result = document.Insert(model);
        TempData["Message"] = "Project Added";
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["Message"] = "Project Already Exists";
        return View("Insert", model);
    }
}
```

My model:

```cs
public class Projectdata
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("pname")]
    public string pname { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("pdesc")]
    public string pdesc { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("sdate")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime sdate { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("edate")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime edate { get; set; }
    public List<Team2> teams { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("leader")]
    public string leader { get; set; }
}

public class Team2
{
    [BsonElement("username")]
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```

I can read all multiple values fine but creating a new entry is where I am facing trouble.
Below is the sample data to be added:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5f93cf48a591c562654d4ded"),
"pname" : "demo1",
"pdesc" : "this is a demo project",
"sdate" : "24-10-2020",
"edate" : "25-10-2020",
"teams" : [ 
    {
        "username" : "ManushPandya"
    }, 
    {
        "username" : "KuntalVakil"
    }
],
"leader" : "ManushPandya"
}
```

How do I store multiple values in teams field? I am using check boxes to let user select those multiple values in a view.

Comment: side note: numbering your variables is a very bad habit (document2, model1...etc), treat your variables like your babies, name them properly!

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but `Insert` doesnt seem to be a method on the collection. Use `InsertOne`. [Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-c-sharp-and-mongodb--creating-documents). If you have your own method to insert, can you share that.